# Mapstruct - How can call Collection.clear() on else condition

Tags: java, mapstruct

MapStruct generates the following code on Collections mapping:

```java
if (entity.getCollection() != null) {
    Set<AnotherEntity> set = AnotherMapper.toEntities(request.getCollection());
    if (set != null) {
        entity.getCollection().clear();
        entity.getCollection().addAll(set);
    } else {
        entity.setCollection(null);
    }
}
```

I want to modify it so that MapStruct will generate something similar to this:

```java
if (entity.getCollection() != null) {
    Set<AnotherEntity> set = AnotherMapper.toEntities(request.getCollection());
    if (set != null) {
        entity.getCollection().clear();
        entity.getCollection().addAll(set);
    } else {
        entity.getCollection().clear();
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise me on how to accomplish this?

I tried using `defaultExpression ="java(entity.getCollection().clear())"` but it didn't work correctly because a setter requires a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue at work recently, with entities that threw an error because of the "set to `null`" part. We've worked around it by clearing the collections before calling the MapStruct-generated code, then use `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE` in an `Mapper` annotation for the target property. That does almost the same as your desired code; the only difference is that it moves the `entity.getCollection().clear()` all the way out of this code, even outside the `if (entity.getCollection() == null)` check (which would trigger an NPE). However, if this is a JPA entity, then the collection will never be `null` if the entity came from the database, and the `null` check is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be the solution. I'm interested in managing that through the library's features rather than manual input. Nonetheless, it looks like the only options are to use the BeforeMapping or AfterMapping annotations.

Comment: @AlexanderTsukanov we never even thought about `@BeforeMapping`, that could be an improvement for us. I don't think that you need `@AfterMapping` though.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. This will be introduced with the `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.CLEAR` which is currently planned for version 1.7.0. We're currently focused on finalizing the 1.6.0 release.

For more information see the [github issue 1830](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1830). The `@BeforeMapping` workaround was also mentioned there.